# Convert type needed, but are Task<TUser> and Task<IUser> the same?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.5

I have this code:

```
public class BaanUserStore<TUser> : IUserStore<TUser>, IUserPasswordStore<TUser> where TUser : Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.IUser
{
    public Task<TUser> FindByNameAsync(string userName)
    {
        //Wrong type!!
        return MyUser.Find(userName);            
    }
}

public class MyUser : IUser
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    internal static Task<IUser> Find(string userName)
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

This gives me this error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task' to 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task

Why is this wrong since `TUser` is the same as `IUser`?
How can I solve this?

SOLUTION:

```
public class MyUser : IUser
{
    public MyUser()
    {

    }

    //Added a constructor with IUser as parameter
    public MyUser(IUser user)
    {
        this.Id = user.Id;
        this.UserName = user.UserName;
    }

    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    //The function is now generic
    internal static Task<TUser> Find<TUser>(string userName) where TUser : Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.IUser
    {
        //...

        //Convert to correct type
        if (user != null)
            return (TUser)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(TUser), new object[] { user });
        else
            return default(TUser);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Then how can I work around it in this example?

Comment: Hint: Every `TUser` is a `IUser`, but not every `IUser` is a `TUser`.

Comment: To clarify Dominic Kexel's point: suppose I said: You've got a bowl of FILL IN A FRUIT HERE.  Now you try to put an apple in that bowl and say "well, an apple is a fruit, so I should be able to put it into a bowl of some kind of fruit". But what if you filled in "banana"?  If you put an apple in a bowl of bananas, it's not a bowl of bananas anymore.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `TUser` does not necessarily be the same as the interface `IUser`, it might be some type that inherits from `IUser`. The easiest way to fix it (if it works for you) is to just use `IUser` everywhere:

```
public class BaanUserStore : IUserStore<IUser>, IUserPasswordStore<IUser>
{
        public Task<IUser> FindByNameAsync(string userName)
        {
            //Wrong type!!
            return MyUser.Find(userName);            
        }
}
```

Another way to fix it is to force the static method `Find` return the correct type:

```
internal static Task<TUser> Find<TUser>(string userName) where TUser : Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.IUser
{
    //...
}
```

In this case you would have to explicitly provide the type when calling the method:

```
return MyUser.Find<TUser>(userName);
```

Comment: seems like the only sensible way to fix it to me.

Comment: The second solution works for me, but I have to do somehting like this in the Find function: return (TUser)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(TUser), user);

Answer (score 0):

Your Find method returns a `Task<IUser>` but FindByNameAsync returns a `Task<TUser>`. There is no boxing convertion possible in that way (see the link in comments or [the articles by Eric Lippert](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2007/10/16/covariance-and-contravariance-in-c-part-one.aspx))

You should make your find method generic:

```
internal static Task<TUser> Find<TUser>(string userName)
{
    //...
}
```

Comment: I suspect you also have to delegate the conversion from `IUser` to `TUser` too. I don't see how the implementation could know how to do this. Unless you also duplicate the generic constraint but, if you do that, why not just return `IUser`.

Comment: The BaanUserStore.FindByNameAsync deals with TUser, modifying it to return IUser changes the class beahaviour. It depends on the context but an extra unboxing can make the class completly awful, imagine the impact if List<T>.Where doesn't return an IEnumerable<T> but an IEnumerable<Object>...